# In visual studio 2010 under #ifdefine WINDOWS statements are not compiled

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010

I have written a small conditional statement in a dll project in visual studio 2010 as below.

```
#ifndef WINDOWS
int a=10;
#endif
```

From the above conditional statemnt, for windows operating system this statement(int a=10) should not be included.But this statement (`int a=10`) also included while compiling.

I am unable to find the problem.

Comment: Because `WINDOWS` is not pre-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Since WINDOWS is not defined anywhere, the variable will be included. There is no such pre-defined macro.

Try `#ifndef _WIN32` or `#ifndef __WIN32`.

Answer (score 1):

Macros to identify the OS are defined by the compiler in question.

Quoting from [64-Bit Compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540443.aspx):

### Predefined macros

The compiler defines the following macros to identify the platform.

```
Macro   Meaning
_WIN64  A 64-bit platform.
_WIN32  A 32-bit platform. This value is also defined by the 64-bit compiler for backward compatibility.
_WIN16  A 16-bit platform.
```

The following macros are specific to the architecture.

```
Macro    Meaning
_M_IA64  A 64-bit Intel platform.
_M_IX86  A 32-bit Intel platform.
```